# How to add follow functionality to wordpress author's profile?

Tags: php, wordpress

is there any way to add "follow" functionality to Wordpress ?
so that every logged-in user can follow his favorite author
and ***only*** can see post from authors that he followed them ..
Mr Ryan "A programmer in wordpress forums" told me that i can do this with the following idea :

A possible solution would be that if a logged-in user (call it user #1) is clicking "follow" on another user's profile (call it user #2), you record user #2's ID as meta data on user #1. You can do this via the update_user_meta function. You can then retrieve posts from user #2 by using WP_Query with an author parameter. The author parameter can be an array, so you can get the posts of multiple users that way

and maybe if we make this idea as a function called : "is_followed" which return True and False
Then we can use it in index.php page in the following line :

```
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <div class="entries">
            <?php while( have_posts()  ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div><!-- .entries -->
```

to be something like this

```
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div class="entries">
        <?php while( have_posts() & is_followed  ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div><!-- .entries -->
```

***Sorry I don't know how to write codes :(***

I found a free plugin called: "User profiles" that can create a profile for each author:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-profile/
so that we can put the follow button in it :/

Comment: These isn't a place to request for people to write code for you, it is a place to request help with your code.  If you want some help you will have to do a lot more of the leg work here and people will help you out when you encounter problems.